# Why does Saruman explain the origin of the Orcs to the Uruk-hai chief?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, saruman

In the Fellowship movie, Saruman gives a long speech to the (newly created) Uruk-hai chief about how the Orcs first came into being and then proceeds to ask him about his loyalty. Why does he do this?

Comment: So that the audience understand what's going on and why Saruman suddenly has an army of Orcs at his disposal.

Comment: It looked like he was trying to convince the uruk that he should be loyal to Saruman

Comment: Having sat and watched the film with someone who hasn't read LOTR, I can tell you that this was precisely the moment they realised why Saruman had Orcs.

Comment: Basically, exposition.

Comment: Classic [monologuing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilGloating) (TVTropes link). Villains just can't help but explain their plans, goals, and how generally awesome they are to the hero, a henchman, or if necessary to thin air.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aside from the necessity of informing the audience, I think there are some real in-story reasons that we can attribute to this.

1. Orcs in general did not have much in the way of culture, particularly these Orcs created as they were by Saruman, and so how they perceive themselves, their background, and their place in the world has a lot to do with how they will fight for Saruman.
2. Saruman is moving from a position of actually being very wise and being exalted by those around him to becoming nothing more than a two-bit hack who can't even maintain his position with his own flunkies. And so, within the narrative of the story, this sort of grandiloquent soliloquy delivered to the leader of a group of marauders fits both his background and the general direction of the story.
3. Also, just because it's Tolkien and that stuff isn't going to exposit itself.

Comment: +1 for your second point alone.  Saruman's becoming a bad guy, and his chief sin is that of arrogance.  What's a more classical sign of arrogance than not being able to shut up?